# Trouble simplifying the following expression.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $x = t \cos(2t)$ and let $y = t \sin(2t)$.  Now show the following equation is true.

$$-200xe^{-x^2-y^2}  (\cos2t - 2t \sin2t) - 200ye^{-x^2-y^2} (\sin2t +2t \cos2t) = -200te^{-t^2}$$

Perhaps it's a simple trig substitution but I am falling on my face here.  This is not from a class.  It originated from MIT free courseware.

Comment: Could you use formatting for your equations? It is difficult to read

Comment: Check that I edited your expression correctly.

Comment: There is a typo. Both occurrences of $e^{-x^2+y^2}$ on the LHS should be  $e^{-x^2-y^2}$. Is this a transcription error of yours, or is it in the original ?

Comment: It was a transcription error but it wasn't Rory's.  I fixed it.  I also reworded the problem statement and removed the vast majority of the last paragraph, which I imagine was the leading cause of the downvotes and/or votes to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get you started...

$x = t \cos 2t$ and $y = t\sin 2t$ means:
$$ x^2 + y^2 = t^2 \cos^2 2t + t^2 \sin^2 2t = t^2 \left(\cos^2 2t + \sin^2 2t\right) = t^2$$

So the LHS in the original equation becomes:
$$-200 \cdot t \cos 2t \cdot e^{-t^2}  (\cos2t - 2t \sin2t) - 200 \cdot t \sin 2t \cdot e^{-t^2} (\sin2t +2t \cos2t)$$

Comment: @JuliusMazzarella, it appears that the answer has actually not been accepted.  You can do so by [clicking on the checkmark icon next to the answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).  In any case I am glad to hear that my answer helped!

Comment: Sorry, didn't know I was supposed to check it.  I went ahead and accepted answer. Your explanation  helped. I see points by my name go up and down but do not know why.

Comment: No problem at all!  Thanks.  You'll understand the points, etc., if you stick around here for a while.